# I cant cd hidden files/dir

Tags: bash, cd-command

I have been working on git a little bit and i tried to cd into `/home/pi/Desktop/python_git/.git` But it complained there was no directory called `/.git`. I know that this is because it begins with a `.` and is therefore hidden, but I don't know the proper argument and when I run `man cd` it says `No manual entry for cd`.

I am running  Debian Linux on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: terdon's answer gives most of the information you're looking for; to find the documentation for `cd`, look for `cd` in the [`bash(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) manpage — run `PAGER='less -p^[\ ]*cd' man bash` to find the info on your system.

Comment: Or just run `help cd`. Shell builtins don't have man pages but (at least in some shells) they have their documentation in the `help` command.

Answer (score 6):

If the error your received was about `/.git`, then you must have tried to run

```
cd /.git
```

That would look for a directory called `.git` in the `/` directory. You want to simply run:

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop/python_git/.git
```

Or, if you are already in `/home/pi/Desktop/python_git/`, just

```
cd .git
```

The hidden files and directories are just like the regular ones. They are simply not listed by default. Apart from that, you can interact with them just like with any other directory or file.

Comment: A less-obvious way this can happen is if you do `cd $VAR/.git` thinking/expecting VAR is set to an appropriate path but it isn't, or similarly `cd $(blech)/.git` expecting that command to output something but it doesn't.